# Joining 2 DELETE queries (how & performance)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, sql-delete

I have 2 MySQL tables having different amount and types of columns. But there's one column of type DATETIME that is called the same in both: **expires**.

I'm now using 2 queries:

```
"DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE `expires` < UTC_TIMESTAMP()"
"DELETE FROM `table2` WHERE `expires` < UTC_TIMESTAMP()"
```

**Q1:** I have never used the `DELETE` query for multiple tables that have no connections so I couldn't figure out the right way to create a single query. Is it possible at all without using `COMMIT`?

**Q2:** I don't have many records in the DB yet so I can't test the performance difference between using 2 queries from PHP or using a single one to delete the *expired* records. Does anybody know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerning about time issues for example, the first query will take 1 minute to execute but this will be a problem for your system (the second table values will expire 1 minute + second query execution time later), you might use them together with a transaction like:

```
begin transaction
set @ts = utc_timestamp();
delete from table_1 where expires< @ts;
delete from table_2 where expires< @ts;
commit
```

and they will be both updated at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. It seems using a transaction is the way to go for best performance. Did you mean 1 second btw?

Comment: Will these timestamps be exactly the same or would you create a variable for the timestamp and use that instead?

Comment: you're right. creating a variable for the timestamp would make things better. 1 minute was an example. it may take 100ms or 1 day who knows :)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete from two tables with one query:

```
DELETE FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON (join_condition) WHERE table1.expires < UTC_TIMESTAMP() AND table2.expires < UTC_TIMESTAMP
```

This only makes sense if the JOIN is correct on your data model.

As far as I can tell, there is no reason for the multiple table syntax to be faster. In fact, because of the need to JOIN, it should be a bit slower (not too much, since after being read from disk, the data will already be in memory so only a bit of processing is lost).

The multiple table syntax is not standard SQL compliant. It's a mysql-specific extension.

Comment: How would you join them when nothing is common in those 2 tables?

Comment: Then it means joining the tables on your data model does not make sense. Use two separate deletes.

Comment: If you are having prolems with execution time, the most effective solution is adding indexes to the "expires" column on both tables. Please also note that UTC_TIMESTAMP() will return two different values on the two calls, because of the time needed for execution of the first query.

Comment: Data in both tables is currently few so I'm trying to implement the most efficient solution taking into account the situation when there will be much more data. So declaring a variable for `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` and using it in transaction makes sense, then..?

Comment: Yes, declaring a variable so that you use the same timestamp for deletion on the two queries is the future-proof solution.